# Advanced Custom Fields - Set Post Object of another post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to solve this issue for a few days now. I hope somebody can help me out here!

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

1. When a post is created (an offer)
2. Create another post (a review)
3. When the review is created
4. Update the post object relationship of the offer to the review

The code I currently have is:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'create_review', 10, 3 );
function create_review( $new, $old, $post ) {

    if ( ( $new == 'publish' ) && ( $old == 'draft' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'ebs_offer' ) ) {

        //when new offer is created
        //create a review post
        $review_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'ebs_review',
        'post_title'    => get_field('ebs_brand_name', $post->ID),
        'post_content'  => 'Content Goes Here',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $review_post );


    } else {
        return;
    }

        if ( ( $new == 'publish' ) && ( $old == 'draft' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'ebs_review' ) ) {

        //when new review is created
        //update the offer post object relationship


    } else {
        return;
    }


}
```

This works fine, I just cannot figure out how to update the post object relationship of the offer. I've tried tonnes of different hooks and functions before anyone says that my code doesn't show that I've tried to solve this myself - I have!

I've stripped my code down so that someone might just be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

For anyone with the same issue, you can use:

update_field($field_name, $post, $post-you-want-to-update-id);

To update.

Pass the entire $post array to update the post object.

Hope this helps someone.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'create_review', 10, 3 );
function create_review( $new, $old, $post ) {

    if ( ( $new == 'publish' ) && ( $old == 'draft' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'ebs_offer' ) ) {

        //when new offer is created
        //create a review post

        global $offer_post_id;
        $offer_post_id = $post->ID;

        // Create post object
        $review_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'ebs_review',
        'post_title'    => get_field('ebs_brand_name', $post->ID),
        'post_content'  => 'Content Goes Here',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $review_post );


    } 

    if ( ( $new == 'publish' ) && ( $old == 'new' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'ebs_review' ) ) {

        //when new offer is created
        //link the review page to the offer
        global $offer_post_id;
        update_field('ebs_review_link', $post, $offer_post_id);

    } else {
        return;
    }


}
```